# MYSQL Statement not producing accurate results (SUM, IF statements and CASE)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

EDIT: It is grabbing all employeehours regardless of the paycode to that employeehours!! How do I select only '01 ordinary','02 overtime 1.5','03 overtime 2.0' ?? That IF statement is not working?

See here for source data photo:

[image]

This is wierd!!!! I am trying to do a full time equivalent head count!! My SQL statement produces a result correctly for one line, and in the next line it is wrong! Both lines are produced from the exact same code!!!!

Here is my query...

```
SELECT Supervisor,
        IFNULL(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 3 THEN 
        IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,CASE WHEN 
        employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' OR employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' OR 
        employeehours.paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0' THEN (SUM(employeehours)-0.4)/7.6 END,CASE WHEN
        employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' OR employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' OR 
        employeehours.paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0' THEN (SUM(employeehours)/7.6) END) END, 0) 
       `Tuesday`,
        FROM payroll.employeedatanew_copy
        JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew_copy.`ID Number` = 
        employeehours.employeeid
        WHERE employeehours.workdate BETWEEN '2013-12-02' AND '2013-12-07'
        GROUP BY supervisor, id number
```

Here is the result!!!! (exluding all days but Tuesday)

[image]

For Supervisor 'Matt Taylor', we have 2 employees.

```
The first has:
8.00 in '01 ordinary'
1.60 in '02 overtime 1.5'
0.00 in '03 overtime 2.0'

The second has:
8.00 in '01 ordinary'
1.17 in '02 overtime 1.5'
0.00 in '03 overtime 2.0'
```

**If you do the calculations manually, you will get 1.21 for the first and 1.15 for the second...!!! WHY is the first one calculating wrong with the exact same coding approach!?**

Comment: Probably a rounding error if I had to guess.

Comment: It can't be as there is no rounding that is that far out....?

Comment: Actually I take that back. That doesn't make sense.

I'd say double check those IF statements see which (if any) of those if statement applies to only the wrong result. I bet it's a simple typo and a piece of math that happens to not apply to one of the two results.

Comment: Lenny! It's grabbing other employeehours that are NOT equal to paycode '01 ordinary','02 overtime 1.5','03 overtime 2.0'. How do I make sure it only grabs those employeehours?? That IF statement is not working...

Comment: Can you just add it to the WHERE? 

... WHERE (employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' OR employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' OR employeehours.paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0') AND employeehours.workdate ...

Comment: sometimes the simple things are what catch me off guard.... thanks lenny.... can't believe I didn't think to do that... haha

Answer (score 0):

Someone had a bowling score computation query that they made more complex than it needed to be.
I helped them by stepping back a bit and trying to simplify it by first building out a pivot into
the respective columns for an each person basis... THEN apply your math...  You might be better
WITH a similar approach...

TRY this just TO confirm the stages of the data...

```
SELECT
      PreSum1.EmployeeID,
      PreSum1.WorkDay,
      PreSum1.RegTime,
      PreSum1.OT15,
      PreSum1.OT20,
      ( PreSum1.RegTime + PreSum.OT15 + PreSum.OT20
         - IF( PreSum1.RegTime = 8, .4, 0 )) / 7.6 as DayTotal
   from 
      ( select 
              EH.EmployeeID,
              DAYOFWEEK(EH.workdate) as WorkDay,
              SUM( IF( EH.paycode = '01 Ordinary', EH.EmployeeHours, 0 )) as RegTime,
              SUM( IF( EH.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5', EH.EmployeeHours, 0 )) as OT15,
              SUM( IF( EH.paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0', EH.EmployeeHours, 0 )) as OT20
           FROM
              EmployeeHours EH
           WHERE
              EH.workdate BETWEEN '2013-12-02' AND '2013-12-07' 
           group by
              EH.EmployeeID,
              DAYOFWEEK(EH.workdate) ) PreSum1
```

This query above does a per single person, per day basis of hours worked for the date range in question... and only for the 3 classification of reg/ot1.5/ot2.0 you are considering.

Then you can wrap that up into this on a per supervisor/employee ID basis

```
SELECT
      NewData.Supervisor,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 1, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Sunday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 2, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Monday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 3, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Tuesday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 4, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Wednesday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 5, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Thursday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 6, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Friday,
      SUM( IF( EmpDaily.WorkDay = 7, EmpDaily.DayTotal, 0 )) as Saturday
   from 
      payroll.employeedatanew_copy NewData
         JOIN ( entire query above ) as EmpDaily
            ON NewData.ID_Number = EmpDaily.EmployeeID
   group by
      NewData.Supervisor
```